# html5 file upload

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

What lib can i use to upload multiple files with the ability to see progress and cancel them mid upload? [this](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload) seems suitable but i'll need to fight the UI because it does things i dont want (such as giving a link) and doesnt do something i want (select a specific file in a list)

I dont want any flash, this has to be html5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use the jquery file upload with your own UI, provided that you are comfortable with jQuery and jQuery UI; we did modify it in 2 hours for image upload wherein you could drag and drop the images in the upload area, and sort the thumbnails of images while they were being uploaded; in the end none of the UI code was original.

Comment: Are you talking about the fileupload i linked to? All i really want is a way to upload with a callback for progress and success with a function to cancel something. hmm, i may just look at all the source files and see how much of a challenge it may be

Comment: Yes, the linked one. It is not the clearest piece of code but it was easier to modify than it seemed at first. And the drag and drop for upload is much nicer way to send needed files than any file dialog, which are quite crap on Linux at least.

Comment: +1 for this answer. The jQuery FileUpload plugin you linked to is the best out there in terms of features and compatibility.

Comment: +1 how could i add additional parameters on upload? (i need to add a session id)

Comment: Does this jquery plugin upload multiple files in a single request? Or is it making many requests? (I mean when you draganddrop 2 files in the same time for exemple)